# Can an Azure Logic App read an excel file from a storage account?

Tags: excel, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an excel spreadsheet residing in a container in an azure storage account.

I can use an Azure Logic App with the "Get Blob Content" to access the file. But I cannot find any documentation discussing actually reading the file within the Azure Logic App from blob storage. Note that there are connectors for accessing Excel files in OneDrive or Office365 but not from a storage account container.

Despite furious searching I have not found any discussion of this use case in Microsoft Documentation or otherwise. Any links would be appreciated.

What is the best approach to read/search an excel file in Azure Logic Apps from Blob Storage?

Comment: What do you mean of `read an excel file` ? Get the content of the excel file in logic app ?

Comment: Correct. Ideally I want to be able to search the excel file for a value and return the rows that match my search criteria. Then use the data from that row in the logic app to say, send an email. This probably means looping through rows and checking the for content in a particular column.

Comment: It seems not exist a good solution to implement this requirement in logic app. Use azure function and write code by yourself as Thiago mentioned is a solution. And do you mind upload the excel to OneDrive and then you can use actions of OneDrive connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an Azure Function to your workflow and easily read the contents of your spreadsheet:

```
public class ExcelFileContentExtractorService : IExcelFileContentExtractorService
{
    public ExcelFileRawDataModel GetFileContent(Stream fileStream)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> cellValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        IWorkbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.Create(fileStream);
        ISheet reportSheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);

        if (reportSheet != null)
        {
            int rowCount = reportSheet.LastRowNum + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                IRow row = reportSheet.GetRow(i);
                if (row != null)
                {
                    foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        var cellValue = cell.GetFormattedCellValue();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellValue))
                        {
                            cellValues.Add(cell.Address.FormatAsString(), cellValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return new ExcelFileRawDataModel()
        {
            Id = cellValues["A6"],
            CarBrand = cellValues["B6"],
            CarModel = cellValues["C6"],
            CarPrice = decimal.Parse(cellValues["D6"]),
            CarAvailability = int.Parse(cellValues["E6"])
        };
    }
}
```

source: https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Extract-Excel-file-content-with-Azure-Logic-Apps-and-Azure-Functions/

Comment: Thank you for this reference. Is an Azure Function the only way to consume excel files from a storage account?

Comment: I'm not 100% if it's the only option, but it definitely will give you a better flexibility when reading the content

Answer (score 1):

And here I will add what I have learned.

Despite native support for reading excel files from OneDrive and Sharepoint at the time of this writing Microsoft Product managers somehow missed that Azure customers may wish to read their content from within Azure (storage account blob) with Azure tools such as Logic Apps.

The only solution at the time of this writing is to create an Azure Function that generates the SAS token and reads the blob.

As a result  I have marked Thiago's response as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do same with CSV and didnt make a lot of progress. It is clumsy to try and parse file contents in my experience. There are a few 3rd party plug-ins (connectors) for logic-apps, but I'm reluctant to use them since I believe the data is send to the 3rd party site as part of processing. If your data isn't particularly sensitive, you could try these connectors.

Comment: Agreed. In addition you have to consider the cost as these are 3rd party licences.